# Build failed -Building a Spring Boot project that connects to a localhost MySQL DB instance with a Jenkins server using Maven

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jenkins, cicd

I have a Spring Boot service/application/project that connects to a localhost MySQL db instance in a Docker container during startup to delete and insert some data. If I do not start the Docker container first before running the Spring Boot service, else JDBC/MySQL connector issues occur.

Recently, I've been trying to learn how to build a CI/CD pipeline. I have Jenkins and Maven installed in one EC2 instance (**Jenkins_server**) that automatically pulls code changes from GitHub and builds it. Then, it deploys the application/service to another EC2 instance with Tomcat installed (**Tomcat_server**). Builds and deployments succeed without issue whenever the Spring Boot application does not use an external MySQL database. However, whenever I try to do the same for applicaitons which require a MySQL db instance to be running locally beforehand, builds in **Jenkins_server** fail.

Among the error outputs are:

`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

and

`org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution`

My instinct is that it is due to the fact that no local instance of a MySQL db can be found whenever the build is being performed, just as a similar issue will occur whenever I try running the Spring Boot service in my local machine without stating the MySQL db Docker container first.

My question is, how do I solve this issue?
I've tried:

1. Running a MySQL Docker container in **Jenkins_server**. Result is that the server stops responding to input and requires a restart, effectively preventing any builds from occuring in this EC2 instance.
2. Changing the "localhost" of `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${RDS_HOSTNAME:localhost}:${RDS_PORT:3306}/${RDS_DB_NAME:todos}` in application.properties of the Spring Boot application to the IP addres of **Tomcat_server**. Result is the same error outputs mentioned previously (JDBC communicaitons link failures).

Jenkins server build configurations are shown in these images: https://imgur.com/a/GPSg0C7

Here is the full build error output form Jenkins_server that I've copied from the managament console: https://pastebin.com/ZYmmYARN

Here is the application.properties of my Spring Boot application: https://pastebin.com/0rNN2PmY

I've tried searching for answers on Google and StackOverflow for 10 hours, but I'm not even sure which answers are relevant or that I should follow. I'm still a beginner in regards to DevOps skills, so I'm really clueless as to ow should I proceed. Would really appreciate some help with this issue!

*Note that all instance IP addresses shown are invalid.